# Manejo de arreglos con hilos, C

Tags: array, c, hilos

Lenguaje de programación: C
Tengo un problema con este código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void* genArreglo_hilo(void *arr){


    int flag = 0, rdm;


    while(flag != 1){
    for (int i = 0; i<7 ;i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        rdm = rand() % 126 + 32;
        arr[i] = rdm;                    Error "Invalid use of void expression"
    }
    flag = 1;
    }
 return 0;
}

/* int validar(char *aux){
    int flag= 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++ ){
        if (aux[i] == aux[i-1]){
            flag = 0;
        }
        else {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
} 
*/


int main(){



    pthread_t hilo/*, hilo2, hilo3, hilo4*/;

    char arr1[7]= {0}/*, arr2[7]= {0}, arr3[7]= {0}, arr4[7]= {0}*/;


    pthread_create (&hilo,  NULL, genArreglo_hilo, arr1);


    /*pthread_create (&hilo2, NULL, genArreglo_hilo, &arr2);
    pthread_create (&hilo3, NULL, genArreglo_hilo, &arr3);
    pthread_create (&hilo4, NULL, genArreglo_hilo, &arr4);*/


    pthread_join (hilo, NULL);
    /*pthread_join (hilo2, NULL);
    pthread_join (hilo3, NULL);
    pthread_join (hilo4, NULL);*/


}
```

ya he buscado información sobre como manejar arreglos utilizando hilos, pero no consigo entenderlo del todo ni que mi programa haga lo que quiero, me seria de mucha ayuda si alguien me puede explicar o decirme donde puedo encontrar información más relevante.

El objetivo es manejar arreglos que se generen con hilos y se validen para finalmente guardarlos en un archivo txt. De momento tengo comentado algo de código ya que pienso que es mejor que funcione primero para 1 arreglo y después puedo repetir lo mismo para los 3 restantes. De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema? `void*` es un puntero sin tipo. Necesitas convertirlo al tipo correspondiente para poder modificarlo. `char* arreglo = arr;`. En C++ la conversión debe ser explícita `(char*)arr`.

Comment: Bueno lo que yo entiendo del hilo, es que al estar manejando el arreglo no le paso el arreglo como parámetro si no el puntero para modificar el mismo desde el hilo, y no retorna nada si no que modifica el arreglo, aún no lo entiendo del todo. El lenguaje es C no C++

Comment: Tal y como comenta @Mateo puedes añadir al principio de la función `char* arreglo = arr;` para posteriormente hacer `arreglo[i] = rdm;` o simplemente reemplazar esta linea por `((char*)arr)[i] = rdm;`. De todas formas también me he fijado que `rdm = rand() % 126 + 32;` puede obtener valores que exceden 127, el cual es el máximo valor que puede almacenar un char con signo. Esto deberías arreglarlo también.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya lo entendí, si, debo de realizar algunas correcciones en el código. De nuevo muchas gracias por su ayuda, a los 2.